# How to retrieve data based on a unique identifier using Nest-API and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, nest-api

Currently I'm monitoring Nest devices and can act upon a change. With this code:

```
fireRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
fireRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  var snap = snapshot.val();
  console.log(snap);
});
```

This work fine, however, I would like to access some data without having to listen for it. Above function will return ALL devices, making it hard to monitor for a specific change. Given that above function will return a object like this, with unique identifiers such as `structure_id`.

```
{devices: {},
 metadata: {},
 structures{}
}
```

How could I access the properties of specific device, for example:

```
get wss://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/_uniqueID
```

This obvious wont work. Is there a similar command?

Comment: Rather than read at the root, you could add `fireRef.child('devices/thermostats/<_uniqueID>').on('value', ...)` to retrieve data for that single item.

Comment: See [Creating a Firebase Reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references)

Comment: You may also be interested in [once()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) and the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/).

Answer (score 0):

To receive only the structure from "x" down you'd need to set up your read with the data pointing to that path. This is a `.bat` example. You're first `OAuth` will redirect to some new URL. If your read method accounts for redirects then you can just use `https://developer-api.nest.com`. Source is located on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/P5NYdMmh). Comment/uncomment as necessary. This example uses `CURL`. This assumes you already have the access token.

```
set access_token=[you'll get this from a successful oauth]

set new_url=https://firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553

rem VALUE_CONFIG
set value1=target_temperature_f
set value2=name
set value3=hvac_mode
set value4=ambient_temperature_f
set value5=target_temperature_high_f

set value_name=%value3%

rem DEVICE_CONFIG
rem virtual:
set dev_id1=[manually enter example dev_id]
rem real:
set dev_id2=[manually enter example dev_id]

set dev_id=%dev_id1%

set url=https://developer-api.nest.com/%struct_name%.json?auth=%access_token%
set url_by_id=%new_url%/devices/thermostats/%dev_id%.json?auth=%access_token%
set url_by_value=%new_url%/devices/thermostats/%dev_id%/%value_name%.json?auth=%access_token%

rem TOGGLE FOR GET
set GET_DATA=true
rem TOGGLE FOR GET

rem GET_DATA
set get_struct=curl\curl.exe -k -L %url%
set get_by_id=curl\curl.exe -k -L %url_by_id%
set get_by_value=curl\curl.exe -k -L %url_by_value%

set get_url=%get_by_id%

if defined GET_DATA echo %get_url%
if defined GET_DATA echo.
if defined GET_DATA %get_url%
if defined GET_DATA echo.
```